# How to get Silverlight's bitmapimage pixel height before it is drawn to canvas?

Tags: silverlight, bitmapimage

I have an Image, which I need to scale based on the image's pixel values. 
When I create the bitmapImage, the pixels (height and width) are both 0.

Is there a way to get height and width before the image is drawn to the canvas?

Comment: Can you provide the code on how you are specifying/loading the bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I needed to measure the height of a row (with content) being added to a Grid before adding it to the Grid.  Short answer - it can't be done.

Long answer - it can be done.  In my code-behind, I created a dummy Grid not a part of the UI.  I would add the row to it, and then call .Measure on the dummy Grid that would give me the rendered size of the row.  Then I could just add the row to the actual Grid on the UI.

I suspect you could try the same approach with your image.  Create a dummy Canvas, add the image to the Canvas, and see how big it is.

Comment: Didn't see how old this question was.  Still, maybe the answer can be useful to someone.